# What is the default password for SQL Server 2012 if I didn't put a password in the setup?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012

I installed SQL Server 2012 without putting a password .

What is the default password for SQL Authentication , where the login is `sa` ?

**Login : sa** and **Password : blank** , didn't do the trick ...

Thanks

Comment: Did you enable SQL Authentication?

Comment: Have u tried to check in Security Tab by login in Windows Authentication...

Comment: Windows authentication is enabled by default so log using "integrated authentication" as an administrator. Then you can add other users as you need.

Answer (score 4):

If you install SQL Server with Windows Authentication mode and want to change it, you need to do 2 different things:

1. Go to SQL Server Properties/Security tab and change the mode to SQL Server authentication mode
2. Go to security/logins, open SA login properties

a. Uncheck "Enforce password policy" and "Enforce password expiration" check box there if you decide to use weak password

b. Assign password to SA user

c. Open "Status" tab and enable login.

Answer (score 2):

Just try to Login in by Windows Authentication.

After Login, Look for Security Tab in Server tree,in that Login and then sa.

Click on properties and change the password.

Do let me know if it dosen't works..