# What is default Password for SA in SQLSERVER 2008R2

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying the SQL server authentication .username is SA but not able to get the default password.please help me .

also tried the blank password but with no success.Is there nothing we can do to solve this problem or was this bug in sql server 2008?

Since most database come with default username and password.

Comment: While this is a bad question, "this type of information ought not be on StackOverflow!" is a completely and utterly stupid and invalid close reason.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the default password for SQL Server 2012 if I didn't put a password in the setup?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24217540/what-is-the-default-password-for-sql-server-2012-if-i-didnt-put-a-password-in-t)

Comment: This question can be answered by a google search `sql server 2008 no default password sa` that's the how

Comment: I think i need to find the answer on my own . will post the answer once i find the solution for this.

Answer (score 6):

There is none. SQL Server for many many versions asks for one during setup and does not accept empty.

Comment: can you please give solution for this

Comment: To be fair, this answer is not entirely complete. If SQL Server authentication is not enabled during setup, then no password needs to be entered during setup. SQL Server authentication can be enabled after installation, and then it still does not require any password to be entered for the sa account. But "There is none" is correct nonetheless.

Comment: finally got the answer, you can directly change the password for SA user

Comment: @spcool But that is not what you asked, you know. You do not ask whether or how to change it - you ask what the default is.

Comment: @ TomTom yeah  i know but anyone should have suggested me that jst try to change the password..